# PHP 'explode' String Based On Array Value

Tags: php

I have this array :

```
$coins = array('BTC','ETH','USDT','BCH');
```

and I have this string :

```
$string = 'ETHBTC';
```

how to split / explode `$string` based on array value, so that the result will be like this :

```
ETH_BTC
```

Comment: Explode is for turning a string into an array. Your result isn't an array, it's another string.

Comment: Do you want to find all the matches for the items in `$coins` in the string, then concatenate them with `_`? Can there be text in `$string` that doesn't match anything in `$coins`? What should happen to that extra text?

Comment: So basically underscore around array values found in string? What about overlapping array values?

Comment: You can turn `$coins` into a regexp like `/BTC|ETH|ESDT|BCH/`, then use `preg_match_all()` to find all the matches. Put them into an array and use `implode()`.

Comment: You should use `preg_match_all`, not `preg_match`. Show how you tried to use it.

Comment: Is it always two currencies?

Comment: @Andreas : yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_replace and insert an underscore after each match then rtrim off the trailing underscore.

```
$coins = array('BTC','ETH','USDT','BCH');

$string = 'ETHBTC';

echo rtrim(preg_replace("/". implode("|", $coins) . "/", "$0_", $string), "_");
```

Comment: thank you, @Andreas. it works as I expected. thank you so much

Comment: @SaintRobson Make sure to order `$coins` from longest length to shortest length because if a currency's chars are a part of another currency then you will have issues. For example if `$coins = array('BTC','ETH', 'USD', 'USDT','BCH');` and `$string = 'ETHBTCUSDT';` then the output is `ETH_BTC_USD_T`. Since you have no proper delimiter it is next to impossible to decipher situations in which one currency's beginning is another's ending.

Comment: @SaintRobson for example `$coins = array('BTC','ETH','THE','TH'); $string = 'BTCTHETH';` produces `BTC_THE_TH` but it should have been `BTC_TH_ETH`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it's always two currencies so it shouldn't matter

Comment: My first comment still applies then unless you can guarantee that a cryptocurrency's shorthand is currently not and never will be a substring of another's shorthand.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Not so sure about that. https://3v4l.org/1jUDF should be a valid test? Either way, with crap data in you can only expect the code to do it's best to parse. There will always be cases that it will fail due to the data in.

Comment: @Andreas Try `$string = 'USDUSDD';`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I know. Again, with crap in you can only get glorified crap out. Always putting the longest first will also fail in some cases such as this https://3v4l.org/7JJrq